# MySQL cast formatted date to int

Tags: mysql, casting

I want to get the format `YYYYMM` as an integer:

```
select CAST(DATE_FORMAT('2018-09-12','%Y%m') as INT)
```

Unfortunately, I get a syntax error. I would like it to return the number `201809`.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must replace INT type to SIGNED or UNSIGNED for example

```
SELECT CAST(DATE_FORMAT('2018-09-12','%Y%m') AS SIGNED)
```